# Create Table Database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

Somehow I can't create a Table in the database by running the code. However, SQL inquiry works...

I was thinking it's my connection string. I tried both with my.settings and as plain text however I get no errors and it still doesn't work.

```
Dim conStr As String = My.Settings.SDB
    Dim objCon As New SqlConnection(conStr)
    Dim obj As SqlCommand
    Dim strSQL As String

    Try
        objCon = New SqlConnection(conStr)
        objCon.Open()
        obj = objCon.CreateCommand()
        strSQL = "CREATE TABLE Names (Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, LastName VARCHAR(30), FirstName VARCHAR (30))"
        'Execute
        obj.CommandText = strSQL
        obj.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    objCon.Close()
    objCon = Nothing
```

No errors, works in actual SQL command..

Comment: You Dim objCon as New SqlConnection and in your try you do it again?

Comment: Is your connection in VB using the same user (from same client machine) as the "actual SQL command"?

Comment: Try moving your `strSQL` up one line and then do this `obj = New SqlCommand(strSQL, objCon)`... and finally remove `obj.CommandText` you wont need it. Also, look into `Using` statements.

Comment: I tried different connection still no luck. Yes SQL and CLient are the same. Tried and still no luck. However, While app running it if I try to create a table it tells me table already exist however the database is empty. Somehow Data does Not transfer to database.

Comment: If it is telling you the table already exists, but you don't see it when looking through other methods, double check the connections again. This wouldn't be the first time someone had a problem here and it turned out there program was running against a different server or schema.

Comment: OK, guys, I figured it out.... Its a terrible VB.net emulation - it creates a 2nd Database in DEBUG folder and applies changes to it instead of original location. You will have to add this extra Database to your server explorer in order to see the changes. Credit - "https://forums.asp.net/t/1378272.aspx"

Comment: Sidenote: MySQL is a specific implementation of SQL, just like Oracle, Postgres, MS SQL Server, Sqlite..... so you should probably remove that tag.

Answer (score 1):

OK, guys, I figured it out.... There is nothing wrong with the code. Its a terrible VB.net emulation - it creates a 2nd Database in DEBUG folder and applies changes to it instead of the original location. You will have to add this extra Database to your server explorer in order to see the changes. Credit - "https://forums.asp.net/t/1378272.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim conStr As String = My.Settings.SDB
    Dim objCon As New SqlConnection(conStr)
    Dim obj As SqlCommand
    Dim strSQL As String

    Try
        objCon = New SqlConnection(conStr)
        objCon.Open()
        strSQL = "CREATE TABLE Names (Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, LastName 
        VARCHAR(30), FirstName VARCHAR (30))"     
        obj = objCon.CreateCommand(strSQL)                   
        obj.CommandText = strSQL
        obj.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Exit Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
    objCon.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Table Created Successfully","Anything")
    End Try
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer unfortunately "obj = objCon.CreateCommand(strSQL)" error

Comment: Just remove the conStr from global variable like exm: Dim objCon As New SqlConnection()

Comment: or u can remove the objCon  = New SqlConnection(conStr) from try , the reason is " you aleady declear and assign it as global

Comment: I have removed "objCon = New SqlConnection(conStr)" since it is a repeat.... but still the same error. Sorry little confused regards to "Dim objCon" since it defines my connection string. But even if I do as "Dim objCon As SqlConnection" and specify constring after still the same error. From what I understand its becasue "objCon" already has a value and we can't add "Strql"